# SSE4.1 automatically put in string comparison on newer gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, sse

I searched the gcc 4.8.1 documents but couldn't find an answer to this:

I have some SSE4.1 code and fallback code, at runtime I detect whether the system supports SSE4.1 and in case it doesn't, I use the fallback code.

So far so good, but with latest gcc versions this is what happens:

**- my application crashes because SSE4.1 instructions are being spread throughout the code every time a string comparison is performed**

Since I'm compiling all my files with -msse41 this sounds reasonable but crashes my code. My question is this: is there any way to restrict SSE41 usage to just that code which makes use of SSE4.1? Unfortunately these are header files used everywhere so it would be rather difficult to just compile those translation units with msse41

Comment: As you manually have code that uses SSE4.1, there should be no need for the `-msse41` flag. It tells the compiler that the platform the program is compiled for always will have SSE4.1 and the code gnerator and optimizer will use that fact. The flag have nothing to do with your ability to use SSE4.1 specific code.

Comment: If I don't use msse41 on those files, I get a "#error SSE4.1 Instruction set not enabled" by gcc

Comment: *"my application crashes because SSE4.1 instructions are being spread throughout the code every time a string comparison is performed"* - Then you should rather try to fix that by making your own SSE4.1 code not interfere with any other possible SSE4.1 code (which shouldn't happen anyway, given properly wirtten SSE intrinsics), instead of artificially prohibiting any other code to use SSE4.1 (who knows, maybe those string comparisons buy you more performance than your own SSE4.1 blocks if seeing the whole application).

Comment: @ChristianRau Isolate SSE4.1 code in specific source files, then compile just _those_ with the `-msse41` flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of GCC 4.8, you can use multi-versioned functions, see http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/changes.html, look for "Function Multiversioning Support with G++". Disclaimer: I did not use this (as of yet).