# Tell GCC "I want to use SSE4.1, but ONLY in the places I want!"

Tags: c++, gcc, sse

As the subject says.. how do I tell GCC to allow me to use SSE4.1 intrinsics but NOT optimize with SSE4.1 (e.g. by putting SSE4.1 string comparisons) throughout all the rest of the code in the same translation unit?

Comment: Why? Have you followed the advice in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215775/sse4-1-automatically-put-in-string-comparison-on-newer-gcc, and fixed your SSE code?

Comment: I did that but still can't solve the header problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Function Attributes](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) to change the compilation target options on a per-function basis. The GCC manual gives the following examples:

```
int core2_func (void) __attribute__ ((__target__ ("arch=core2")));
int sse3_func (void) __attribute__ ((__target__ ("sse3")));
```

You can also disable on a per-function basis, e.g.:

```
int no_sse3_func (void) __attribute__ ((__target__ ("no-sse3")));
```

Comment: This might really solve my problem, but what about the header files? I can't include them "#error SSE4.1 instruction set not enabled" if I don't enable -msse41 for the entire translation unit

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the suggestion by [@PeterCorlett](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20223986/1441), which gives you per-function control, if it's possible, you could just refactor your code so the parts you want SSE4 enabled in are in one translation unit, and then specify different `gcc` options for that single file.

However, if the parts where you want to control the code generation are sub-function granularity, I'm not sure you can accomplish what you want (other than by splitting the functions and losing the inline nature of those blocks in the process).